# Docker npm install with cache

Tags: docker, npm

I am using `python:3:10-alpine` as a base docker image, but I need `npm` to install some front-end JavaScript libraries.

When I ask `pip` to install libraries I can have it use a cache to save downloading packages every time I build.  E.g.

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Is there a similar incantation to help `npm install`?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Is NPM supposed to support this? What libraries?

Comment: @music2myear: Google search is turning up pre-configured node.js docker images, and as I have already customized my python/flask image quite a bit, I'd prefer to start from there.  I'm not an npm expert, but most package managers use a cache. Libraries: purescript, halogen, purescript-formless, Three.js.  Not sure why the particular libraries matter to this question.